# Custom figure numbering for a specific chapter ( Annexe ) | Custum Specific Chapter numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

So, as i defined my "Annexe" chapter, the figures in this chapter, since it doesn't have a number  , it has appeared in the list of figures as it is belongs to the last defined chapter with numbering .

This is how i listed figures :

```
\listoffigures
\minitoc
```

This is how i defined the chapter :

```
\chapter*{Annexe A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexe A}
\markboth{Annexe A}{Annexe A}
```

Current State:
[image: Current State]
What i want to achieve as figure IV.57 actually belongs to Annexe chapter and not the IV chapter:
[image: What i want to achieve]

Comment: Hi Nizou and welcome to TeX.SE! I am sorry but from your explanation, it is not entirely clear, what you wan to achieve. Can you maybe post an example of what you currently have and what you finally want to achieve? A hand drawn sketch might help as well.

Comment: Thank you TobiBS . I just Added 2 pictures that describes the current state and the wanted result. I Hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: OK and what document class are you using? Are you sure you want to have A.57 and not A.1?

Comment: In most questions including the current one, please provide an [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), this helps others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear that this is right, but

Replace

```
\chapter*{Annexe A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexe A}
\markboth{Annexe A}{Annexe A}
```

with

```
\appendix
\chapter{}% You can give a title here if you want
```

Your language selection may already define `\appendixname` as "Annexe", but if not, put `\renewcommand\appendixname{Annexe}` in the preamble.

And you will probably want one of the appendix-support packages to make the "chapter" and page head formatting use the "Annexe" word. That will depend on what your document class does already, and what it is compatible with. If you can't use a package, you can continue your more hands-on approach

```
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexe}
\appendix
\chapter*{Annexe A}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexe A}
\markboth{Annexe A}{Annexe A}
```